# How can I make @Resource annotation work with Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource

I have this simple code:

```
public class TestClass {

    @Resource(name="jdbc/superblog")
    DataSource dataSource;

    public void testMethod() throws SQLException {
       /* try {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/superblog");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

So if I use the code with the try / catch block, it works.. ( If I comment the @Resource annotation. )

However code above as it is will not work, because **dataSource** will be null.

How can I make the @Resource annotation work? I tried both Tomcat 6 and 7, no difference.

Comment: Some of the answers you can find  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878835/getting-null-pointer-exception-resource-annotation-in-tomact-7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make the @Resource annotation work?

You must add the @Resource annotation to a servlet, filter or other supported class.  The [servlet 3.0 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr315/index.html) states that containers are not required to perform annotation injection on classes that do not implement any of the following interfaces.

```
javax.servlet.Servlet
javax.servlet.Filter
javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
javax.servlet.ServletContextAttributeListener 
javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener
javax.servlet.ServletRequestAttributeListener
javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener
javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionAttributeListener
javax.servlet.AsyncListener
```

Since your test class does not implement any of these interfaces I would not expect resource injection to work.

Comment: Servlet 3.0 specification link is broken.